# ! File ended while scanning use of \@imakebox

Tags: tables, errors

I´m trying to build a table, in the begining it´s fine, suddently it comes out an error, which I don´t understand . Maybe someone knows where is the problem?
Thank you in advance.

```
Error msg:
! File ended while scanning use of \@imakebox.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> ./test.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

My script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{13pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            style=authoryear,
            natbib=true, 
            style=numeric-comp
            ]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\hrulefill
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{6}{c|}
& {$\tvar{delta}_{\mathrm{max,X}}$(m)} & {$\Theta (degree)$} & {$\tvar{delta}_{\mathrm{max,Y}}$(m)} & {$ \Theta (degree)$} & {$\tvar{delta}_{\mathrm{max,Z}}$(m)}  & {$\Theta (degree)$}  \\
\hline
FH & 0.262 & -146.422 & 0.289 & -1.680 & 0.100 & -2.256\\
\hline
UT & 0.163 & -0.122 & 0.210 & 21.968 & 0.080 & 9.276\\
\hline
LT & 0.196 & -0.122 & 0.166 & 32.315 & 0.136 & 8.230\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is due to a missing `}` after `\begin{tabular}{|c|*{6}{c|}`, try it with `\begin{tabular}{|c|*{6}{c|}}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a missing }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `{` in your column designation; it should be `{|c|*{6}c|}`.

Comment: Thank you, I meant to add | but added { i guess. But it doesn´t have a line on the top of the table, and also vertical lines inside table are missing. Do you know how to solve this? Thank you!@Herb Schulz

Comment: “You have a missing `}` in your column designation: it should be `{|c|*{6}{c}}`” would be a better help.

Comment: thank you, but the top line over the table is still missing... @egreg

Comment: @Vivian `\hline`